# AsP.Net MVC 5 how to call a function in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have ASP.Net MVC 5 application I want to call a method from view how can I do it?

my code:

My UsersList function:

```
    public ActionResult UsersList()
    {

        var User_VM = new UserVM
        {
            MyUsers = context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.Email).Include(u => u.Roles).ToList()
        };

        return View(User_VM);

    }
```

UsersList View:

```
@foreach(var user in Model.MyUsers)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@user.Email</td>
        <td>
            @foreach(var r in user.Roles)
            {
                <p>
                    @Html.Action(GetRoleNameById(r.RoleId))
                </p>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and my function in controller:

```
   public ActionResult GetRoleNameById(string RoleId)
    {
        var RoleName = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Id == RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
        return Content(RoleName.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Its a bit unclear why you would want to do this instead of populating the model in the main view in the first place, but its `@Html.Action("GetRoleNameById", new { roleId = r.RoleId })`

Comment: @Html.Action("Controller","Name", new { id = 1 }) 
This is Default.. Change with your own Controller and Method

Comment: I need to call an method or action from View, do you know how to call?

Comment: Try above, it is perfect way to Call

Comment: but why not just `@foreach(var r in user.Roles) { <p>@r.RoleName</p> }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you post your comment as answer that solved my problem thank you

Comment: Still not clear why you would want to do this by calling a controller method (did you check my last comment)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke r.RoleName does not exists its just UserId and RoleId

Comment: You have an `Include(r=> r.Roles)` in your query and assuming `Roles` is type of `IEnumerable<Role>` then you should already have the `RoleName` property - or is `Roles` a different type?

Comment: I tried that but there is no RoleName it just bring UserId and RoleId because in database which it has created has a separate relation table which only contains UserId with RoleId its ASP.Net MVC 5 Identity, I am not sure why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151766/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mehdi-jalal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call your server method by using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object%29) of `Html.Action()` that accepts the action name as the first parameter and the route values as the 2nd parameter

```
@foreach(var r in user.Roles)
{
    <p>@Html.Action("GetRoleNameById", new { roleId = r.RoleId })</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this purpose in many ways, on of them is you call make a ajax call to controller method. Something like this

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ContollerName/GetRoleNameById" + "?RoleId=1", // change controller name here and pass proper role id.
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Done");
            } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Also you can set content type in calling configuration