# How do i pass multiple actionresults from home controller to index.cshtml view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller code. The first method is to get 5 post to display in the homepage.

The second method is to display recent post in the sidebar.

How do I link it to display in the View which already shows the posts for the Index action?

**Controller:**

```
namespace ThelmaBlog.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();   
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var posts = db.Posts.Include(p => p.Author).OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).Take(3);

            return View(posts.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Sidebar()
        {
            var PostsTop5 = db.Posts.Include(path => path.Author).OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).Take(3);

            return View(PostsTop5.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@model List<ThelmaBlog.Models.Post>

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="post col-md-6">
            <h2 class="title">@post.Title</h2>
            <div class="about">
                Posted on <i>@post.Date</i>
                @if (post.Author != null)
                {
                    @:by <i>@(post.Author.FullName + "  (" + post.Author.UserName + ")")</i>
            }
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(post.Body))
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}

@section  Sidebar{



}
```

Comment: Hi, have you try RenderAction in your view? With a partial view

Comment: Use `@{ Html.RenderAction("Sidebar")` in the main view to render the partial view returned by your `Sidebar()` method

Comment: This explain all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647211/asp-net-mvc-5-how-to-call-a-function-in-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Sidebar action so it returns a partial view:

```
public ActionResult Sidebar()
{
    var PostsTop5 = db.Posts.Include(path => path.Author).OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).Take(3);

    return PartialView("_Posts", PostsTop5.ToList());
}
```

Then, create a partial view, called `_Posts.cshtml`, with the following code:

```
@model List<ThelmaBlog.Models.Post>

@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="post col-md-6">
            <h2 class="title">@post.Title</h2>
            <div class="about">
                Posted on <i>@post.Date</i>
                @if (post.Author != null)
                {
                    @:by <i>@(post.Author.FullName + "  (" + post.Author.UserName + ")")</i>
            }
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(post.Body))
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And, finally, change your Index view to this:

```
@model List<ThelmaBlog.Models.Post>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Html.Partial("_Posts", Model)


@section  Sidebar{
    @Html.Action("Sidebar", "Home")
}
```

By the way, neither of your actions return what you have described in your post. They both return exactly the same thing, which is the top 3 posts (not top 5).

Comment: "By the way, neither of your actions return what you have described in your post. They both return exactly the same thing, which is the top 3 posts (not top 5)."    I saw that after posting. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

add your `sidebar` content to new `partialview` and then render this partial view in index

```
 @Html.Action("sidebar") // in your index page
```